# Cambiar Nombres Automatico

Tags: batch

Buen Dia tengo este Scrip que me gustari modificar y que cuando le de doble click me cree ps9999.patch desde el numero 1 SIN estar digitando numeros uno por uno hay alguna manera?

```
@echo off
title Crear Nombres a partir de un solo nombre
color 56
cls
echo Cual es el numero maximo de este Patch? (cantidades entre 1 y 9999)
set /p %numero% = 
REN ps0001.patch ps%numero%.patch
```

Quiero hacer algo asi como cuando uno copia un archivo en el mismo directorio y crea un numero para diferenciar el primer archivo del ultimo copiado pero que este comienze  desde ps0001.patch y termine en ps9999.patch siempre conservando 4 digitos numericos

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que necesitas puedes usar [for /l](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html). Con este comando puedes iterar entre un numero incial y un numero final, con el incremento que necesites. Con el resultado del for, basta con aplicar "0" a la izquierda para conseguir el formato que deseas. Quedaría así

```
@echo off
title Crear Nombres a partir de un solo nombre
REM color 56
cls
echo Cual es el numero maximo de este Patch? (cantidades entre 1 y 9999)
set /p numero=

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%g IN (1,1,%numero%) DO (
    set relleno=0000%%g
    echo copy plantilla.patch ps!relleno:~-4!.patch 
)
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

> ```
> Cual es el numero maximo de este Patch? (cantidades entre 1 y 9999)
> 10
> copy plantilla.patch ps0001.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0002.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0003.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0004.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0005.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0006.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0007.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0008.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0009.patch
> copy plantilla.patch ps0010.patch
> ```

Hay un cambio en la linea del `set /p`, hay que quitar los `%`y el espacio. Suponiendo que tengas un fichero plantilla.patch, la mejor opción es hacer un copy, para así generar copias de tu plantilla con los nombres deseados. En tu script quita `echo` para que haga la copia, yo lo he puesto para ver el resultado ;).